# Can an optical phased array be used to create free-floating holograms?

Tags: optics, hologram

Frustratingly, most sources I've found about optical phased arrays only state that they *can* be used for "holograms" but do not explain what that means.  Can optical phased arrays be used for "Star Trek" style, free-floating, volumetric holograms (at least in principle if not in practice), or are they only capable of displaying a hologram on a screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an optical phased array can be used to display a 3D image -- but there are limitations (of course).  A "[phase-only spatial light modulator](https://holoeye.com/spatial-light-modulators/slm-pluto-phase-only/)" is an example of an optical phased array. The limitations are basically due to the pixel count and the element size.

For example: if the phase-shifting elements are 10 microns x 10 microns and the array is, say, 10 mm x 10 mm, then there are 1000 x 1000 elements.  The maximum diffraction angle of visible light at the array is about 4 degrees due to the element spacing, so the maximum field of view would be about 4 degrees.  You would need to be about a half meter away to see any part of the image with both eyes.

If we ever come up with a spatial light modulator whose elements are sub-micron size and individually addressable - and with a pixel count of, say, 100,000 x 100,000- then we will have the kind of 3D display imagined in SciFi.  However, it will not be a "princess Lea" type 3D display, whose image floats in mid air with nothing between or beyond your eye and the image.  You will only see image points that are on a line between your eye and the array elements.